# Does the assignment code will lead to crash?

Tags: c++, memory, variable-assignment

```
class SMTkrSym {
  enum { SMTKRLEN = 16 };
  uint8     data[SMTKRLEN];

 public:
  SMTkrSym() { memset(&data, 0, sizeof data); }
  SMTkrSym(const char* pIn) { if (Read(pIn) < 0) memset(&data, 0, sizeof data); }
  int16 Show(char* outstr) const; // display ticker symbol
  int16 Read(const char* instr); // read ticker symbol
  bool operator==(const SMTkrSym& rhs) const { return strncmp((char*)data, (char*)rhs.data, SMTKRLEN) == 0; }
  bool operator!=(const SMTkrSym& rhs) const { return !(*this == rhs); }
  bool operator>(const SMTkrSym& rhs) const { return (strncmp((char*)data, (char*)rhs.data, SMTKRLEN) > 0); }
  bool operator<=(const SMTkrSym& rhs) const { return !(*this > rhs); }
  bool operator<(const SMTkrSym& rhs) const { return (strncmp((char*)data, (char*)rhs.data, SMTKRLEN) < 0); }
  bool operator>=(const SMTkrSym& rhs) const { return !(*this < rhs); }
};
unsigned int SMTkrSym::Read(const char* instr)
{
 unsigned int i,j;

 for (i = 0; (i < SMTKRLEN) && *instr; i++)  // display until null
   data[i] = *instr++;
 for (j = i; j < SMTKRLEN; j++)
   data[j] = '\0';      // null out rest of symbol
 return i;     // return actual number of characters
}
```

Usage of this class as below:

```
char pData[] = "helloworldyyyyyy";
char* p = pData;
SMTkrSym key1(p）;
SMTkrSym key2;
key2 = key1;
```

The length of pData is equal to 16.

The SMTkrSym copy constructor will call read function and it will not put '\0' terminator character when the length of instr is larger or equal to 16.

My question is when program run key2 = key1 and does it will lead to crash?

When run key2 = key1 and it will call default assignment operator function.

But key1's data member variable doesn't include terminator character.

My concern is that if default assignment function uses strcpy function to

copy data member variable and it may lead to memory over flow.

I think  if assignment function just look like memcpy(&key2, &key1, 
sizeof(key1)), it won't crash. How does default assignment works?

Comment: "if default assignment function uses strcpy function" - it doesn't, so stop worrying about that, and worry more about how all the rest of your operators rely on a terminator that isn't there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.My understanding is that you mean the operator= is safely copy no matter whether it includes terminator character. Does default assignment function related to compile optimization? Does the default assignment function will change by different compile optimization?

Answer (score 1):

The default compiler-provided `operator=` won't use `strcpy()` to copy `data[]`... it will safely copy all characters in the array, as if by `memcpy` as you say, though it may not actually use `memcpy`.